# Case sentence using SQL

Tags: sql, null, case

I am using double case sentence to get a value from column in a table based on 2 conditions that are available in 2 other columns in same table , and else (otherwise) the function should give null when it is null or 0 when it is 0 .

Example of code is below :

```
CASE CODE 
    WHEN 'ABC' 
        CASE NAME WHEN 'XYZ' 
        THEN 'VALUE' 
        ELSE NULL 
        END
    ELSE NULL 
END
```

The problem is if I use NULL after else then it gives all ( both null values and values with 0 ) as NULL   , or if I use 0 instead of NULL after ELSE then both null and 0 values are given as 0 .
I have tried to write the sentence in many ways but I dont know its not working . Hopefully somebody can give me some good solution regarding this.

Comment: why not `case when code='abc' and name='xyz' then 'value' else null`?

Comment: you should use the following format:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: I formatted your example, but your exmaple is clearly bad, since you're missing a `WHEN` after your second `CASE`, and you have no `THEN` after your first `WHEN`.

Comment: and no `END` for either `CASE`

Comment: What value do you give when the codes don't match and the value is neither 0 nor NULL?  And, as a point of English usage, where you use "sentence" you should be using "expression".

Answer (score 3):

```
CASE WHEN CODE = 'ABC' AND NAME = 'XYZ' THEN 'VALUE' ELSE NULL END
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
CASE WHEN CODE = 'ABC' AND NAME = 'XYZ' THEN 'VALUE' ELSE NULL END
```

This structure of the CASE statement is more flexible than sticking the field name before WHEN.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
(CASE when CODE =  'ABC' and NAME = 'XYZ' 
      THEN 'VALUE' 
      when code = '0' or name = '0'
      then '0'
      ELSE NULL 
 end)
```

Or perhaps it is this (based on the fact that you are trying to get something from a column):

```
(CASE when CODE =  'ABC' and NAME = 'XYZ' 
      THEN value
      when value is NULL or value = 0
      then value
      ELSE NULL 
 end)
```

Based on your comment, I think this will work:

```
(CASE when CODE =  'ABC' and NAME = 'XYZ' 
      THEN value
      ELSE NULL 
 end)
```

Or is it this:

```
(CASE when CODE =  'ABC' and NAME = 'XYZ' and value <> '0'
      THEN 'value'
      when  CODE =  'ABC' and NAME = 'XYZ' and value = '0'
      then '0'
      ELSE NULL 
 end)
```

However, I think this is equivalent to your original nested two-case version.

Comment: I would write like that                                         (CASE when CODE =  'ABC' and NAME = 'XYZ' 
      THEN value
      when value is 0
      then 0      ELSE NULL 
 end)

Comment: @user2453045 . . . Yes, that would be a simplification and equivalent logically.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes this is what I want . I want that when 2 condition are being fulfilled , it gives value in nr , when same 2 conditions are being fullfilled but value in reality is 0 , so it gives 0 , otherwise null ... Could you please help me how to write it in correct sql. Thanks a lot in advance.